# SQL Consultas principiante

Tags: sql

Buenas,alguien sabe que tengo mal?

Tengo estas 3 tablas:

```
  PREGUNTAS       PREGUNTAS_RESPUESTAS      RESPUESTAS
  idpregunta      Idpregunta_res            idrespuestas
  pregunta        idpregunta                respuesta
                  idrespuesta
                  correcto
```

como puedo optener todas las preguntas que hay,junto sus respuestas?

```
select preguntas.pregunta,respuestas.respuesta
from preguntas_respuesta
inner join preguntas on preguntas.idpregunta=preguntas_respuestas.idpregunta_res
inner join respuestas on respuestas.idrespuesta=preguntas_respuestas.idpregunta_res
```

Estoy haciendo eso,pero me muestra solo las preguntas y de cada pregunta una respuesta.Me tendria que enseñar las preguntas,y de cada pregunta 4 respuestas.
Los datos estan bien metidos en las tablas.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checka si esto te sirve.

```
select preguntas.pregunta,respuestas.respuesta
from preguntas_respuesta
inner join preguntas on preguntas.idpregunta=preguntas_respuestas.idpregunta
inner join respuestas on respuestas.idrespuestas=preguntas_respuestas.idrespuesta
```

Answer (score 0):

Mucho más sencillo:

```
SELECT P.PREGUNTA, R.RESPUESTA
FROM PREGUNTAS AS P, RESPUESTAS AS R, PREGUNTAS_RESPUESTAS AS PR
WHERE PR.IDPREGUNTA = P.IDPREGUNTA 
AND PR.IDRESPUESTA = R.IDRESPUESTA
```

Answer (score 0):

fíjate que tienes en el segundo **join**, el *idrespuesta* como el id de la tabla *preguntas_respuestas*.

```
select preguntas.pregunta,respuestas.respuesta
from preguntas_respuesta
inner join preguntas on preguntas.idpregunta=preguntas_respuestas.idpregunta_res
inner join respuestas on respuestas.idrespuesta=preguntas_respuestas.idrespuesta
order by preguntas_respuestas.idpregunta
```

Esto debería a parte de darte las preguntas con sus respuestas ordenarlas por la id de la pregunta, para verlas seguidas.